# Spark Scala Int vs Integer for Option vs StructType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Why is that for a case class I can do

```
fieldn: Option[Int]
```

or

```
fieldn: Option[Integer]
```

but for StructType I must use?

```
StructField("fieldn", IntegerType, true),
```

Comment: [`Int`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) is **Scala** own Integer type, [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is **Java** _boxed_ version of their primitive `int` - both are classes that you can use on Scala code, and the standard library provided implicit conversions between them. Finally, [`IntegerType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType) is an **SparkSQL** type used to represent an integer value in their internal representation, thus is the one used in the schema.

Comment: Sorry, I quite do get what do you mean inconsistent, inconsistent with respect to what?

Comment: I would expect that it would be easier to use both approaches in both places. But that is probably nonsense. Non-standard library I think is the key. Well, work to do, or just the way it is.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get what you are meaning... and its been a while since the last time I used spark, so probably I am speaking no sense. @user10938362 does my first comment contributes to something? or should I delete it?

Comment: You know I spent a fair bit of time working thru all this Null and Int(eger) stuff and I am not silly, but it is fraught with a few hairpin bends imho. I am documenting examples to refer to in future.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It makes perfect sense.  On a second read I am not sure what the question is actually about. Let me remove the comment.

Comment: @thebluephantom So what actually bothers you about `StructField("fieldn", IntegerType, true)`? `IntegerType`? `nullable=true`?

Comment: Some weird stuff on nullable anyway, leave that aside. Just consistency but I get it. Maybe being pedantic but see other answer. Hoping minus 1 reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand why it seems inconsistent - the reason is convenience. It is more convenient to give Spark a `case class` because they are really easy to work with in Scala.

Behind the scenes, Spark is taking the `case class` you give it and using it to determine the schema for your DataFrame. This means that all Java/Scala types will be converted to Spark SQL's types behind the scenes. For example, for the following case class:

```
case class TestIntConversion(javaInteger: java.lang.Integer, scalaInt: scala.Int, scalaOptionalInt: Option[scala.Int])
```

You get a schema like this:

```
root
 |-- javaInteger: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- scalaInt: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- scalaOptionalInt: integer (nullable = true)
```

In the latest version of Spark, the thing that does the conversion for you is an [Encoder](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html). You can see a ton of the conversions in [ExpressionEncoderSuite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86cc907448f0102ad0c185e87fcc897d0a32707f/sql/catalyst/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoderSuite.scala)

Comment: Yep, that makes good sense. Spark vs Scala, implementation of former, just the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

`Optional` type denotes objects that can be undefined (`None`). So it is mostly applicable to data.

There is no position at which it could be meaningfully used in your `StructField` example:

Schema must be defined so

```
Option[StructField]
```

and doesn't provide any information about the type, not is semantically truthful and anything around

```
Option[DataType]
```

or

```
Option[IntegerType]
```

i.e

```
StructField("fieldn", Some(IntegerType): )
```

would make even less sense - either creating object with unclear semantics (former) or impossible API.

Fundamentally `StructType` represent obligatory metadata. It cannot be missing by design, and because of that `Option` doesn't have any place there.

Comment: case class TypeA(field1: Int, field2: Option[String], field3: Boolean)   So we agree no beef on the case class.

Comment: I'm not convinced I stated anything on Option[StructField]  in the question?